# What are the differences between Sri Vaishnavism and Kashmiri Shaivism?

Tags: vedanta, sri-vaishnava, kashmiri-shaivism

I am aware that there are many differences in these two sampradayas. Kashmiri Shaivism being more monistic and Sri Vaishnavism qualified monism etc. In some ways I feel like Kashmiri Shaivism is more similar to Vishishtadvaita Vedanta than to Advaita Vedanta, but I couldn't find someone who made a comparison of the two yet, so it's hard to keep the thoughts organized. I was wondering if anyone have done that yet. Thanks!

Comment: I think Sri Vaishnavism is rather more similar to Shrouta Saiva Siddhanta than it is to Kashmiri Shaivism.

Comment: Thanks! But I'm not familiar with any kind of Shaivism, really.